# Implementing hashmap in C for NAND flash memory

Tags: c, memory, flash-memory

I am trying to implement firmware for a flash storage device. I am trying to create a hashmap to map Logical Block Address to Physical NAND memory. (LBA is a block of 512 bytes). My approach: I am doing this by declaring an array of pointers. I want each pointer to point to pointer to a struct containing a physical address on NAND flash along with some other relevant data which goes like this:

```
typedef struct mapData
{
   uint32_t physicalNand; 
   uint32_t count;  
   bool isLbaUsed;
   bool isLbaValid;
} // these are some data I need to associate with each LBA.

array declaration:
int *arr[MAX_LBA]; // MAX_LBA is the maximum logical block address handled by 
                   // the OS. I wan to represent each index of array as one LBA.
```

I'm new to the entire data structures/algorithm/NAND flash arena (i know the basics of their theory) and would really appreciate some help on this. I seem to get stuck in moving forward with implementation of this hashMap that maps LBA and physical address in C.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a specific question. If you want to see how the "experts" do it then just go look for  the UBI code which does exactly this of mapping from LEBs to PEBs (and more).

Comment: @kaylum: I want to point a unique pba to each pointer in the array. Consider this as a one on one mapping. This is how I want to initialize. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Error correction, wear leveling, etc. are quite some advanced technique and nothing to implement en-passant. Without stating your **specific** problem, your question (whichever that would be) is far too broad.

Comment: @Olaf: Okay.. What I am struggling with is not wear levelling and stuff like that. All I want to do is I need to declare an array of pointers to structs, create a new struct and intialize all the values to 0 and print them. I want to my array of pointers to point to the struct defined above. Can you please help me? I am new to C and pointers!!

Comment: @Gingerbread: You missed my point: that is not a beginner's task. Start with something less advance. A beginner architect will not start with a skyscraper for the first job.